# WSO2 api manager auth types

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

What mean the "Auth Type" in http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/API+Resources?
Do they have any relationship with Grant Types of OAuth2?

Thanks,

Comment: The documentation already explained: *Facilitates resource-level authentication where different levels of authentication can be specified to each HTTP method of the resource.*

Answer (score 0):

They don't have any relationship with OAuth2 grant types.Rather they indicate that, accessing those http verbs are restricted to application subscribers/users etc

Comment: Is there any documentation obout this?

Comment: hope this documentation helps
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OAuth+2.0+Grant+Types+with+WSO2+API+Manager+Implicit